# Example not following: HashMap allows only one key and multiple null values

Tags: java, hashmap, key

Today i read in a book:-

> "HashMap allows one null key and multiple null values in a collection."

```
HashMap<Object,Object> ih=new HashMap<Object,Object>();

   Object o1=null;
   Integer o2=null;

   ih.put(o1,null);
   ih.put(new Integer(2),null);
   ih.put(o2,new Integer(3));
```

This example is putting two null object references in the map.

But the following Example is successfully compiling and running...

I cant figure out why?

Comment: Have you checked what's in the map after your `put` calls?

Comment: Please add the second example that you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry the statement: "This example is putting two null object references in the map." was wrong, First i thought o1 and o2 are putting 2 different object references in HashMap, But then after checking size of hashmap realised that they are considered as same key. So the example is putting object with same key : null, and overriding the previous object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "HashMap allows one null key and multiple null values in a
>   collection."

Allow one `null` key means if you keep adding `null` key, it will overwrite the previous values. Actually, this is true for any key in `HashMap`.

The bottom line is - `HashMap allows only one key`

e.g. if you print the size of your `Hashmap` it will be 2.
`System.out.println("size:: "+ih.size());`

Answer (score 1):

What the book probably means is this:

- among the possible keys of a `HashMap<X, Y>`, there can be a null key;
- whatever the key (even null!), the value associated to this key can be null.

Therefore, it is perfectly normal that your code works. It is just that the book's text here is quite confusing.

---

But of course, this entirely depends on the `Map` implementation; some of them, such as `ConcurrentHashMap`, will not allow null keys or values.